# Saving JPG-Image with JAI's filestore under linux

Tags: java, image-processing, jai

I am trying to solve a homework, in which I should implement a Pipes&Filters-Architecture for a image processing task. But I have problems with the JAI-Framework under Linux (ArchLinux, to be specific).

I am loading a Image with fileload:

```
_image = JAI.create("fileload", file);
```

Later I want to save the image into a separate location:

```
JAI.create("filestore", _image, _filename, "JPEG");
```

I just copied the relevant lines, this is my whole JAI-specific code until now. But when I execute my program I get the following error:

```
Error: One factory fails for the operation "jpeg"
Occurs in: javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.StreamRIF.create(StreamRIF.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.FileLoadRIF.create(FileLoadRIF.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:819)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:799)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.createNS(JAI.java:1099)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:973)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:1621)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.storeFile(ImageSink.java:37)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.write(ImageSink.java:58)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.write(ImageSink.java:16)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.pipesfilters.Pipe.write(Pipe.java:70)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSource.write(ImageSource.java:77)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSource.run(ImageSource.java:84)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.Program.main(Program.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.JPEGImageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(JPEGImageDecoder.java:46)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.CodecRIFUtil.create(CodecRIFUtil.java:88)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.JPEGRIF.create(JPEGRIF.java:43)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.ImageFormatException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 50 more
Error: One factory fails for the operation "stream"
Occurs in: javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.FileLoadRIF.create(FileLoadRIF.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:819)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:799)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.createNS(JAI.java:1099)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:973)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:1621)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.storeFile(ImageSink.java:37)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.write(ImageSink.java:58)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.write(ImageSink.java:16)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.pipesfilters.Pipe.write(Pipe.java:70)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSource.write(ImageSource.java:77)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSource.run(ImageSource.java:84)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.Program.main(Program.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException: All factories fail for the operation "jpeg"
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1687)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.StreamRIF.create(StreamRIF.java:102)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.JPEGImageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(JPEGImageDecoder.java:46)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.CodecRIFUtil.create(CodecRIFUtil.java:88)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.JPEGRIF.create(JPEGRIF.java:43)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.ImageFormatException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 50 more
Error: One factory fails for the operation "fileload"
Occurs in: javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:819)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:799)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.createNS(JAI.java:1099)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:973)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:1621)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.storeFile(ImageSink.java:37)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.write(ImageSink.java:58)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.write(ImageSink.java:16)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.pipesfilters.Pipe.write(Pipe.java:70)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSource.write(ImageSource.java:77)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSource.run(ImageSource.java:84)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.Program.main(Program.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException: All factories fail for the operation "stream"
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1687)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.FileLoadRIF.create(FileLoadRIF.java:144)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException: All factories fail for the operation "jpeg"
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1687)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.StreamRIF.create(StreamRIF.java:102)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.JPEGImageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(JPEGImageDecoder.java:46)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.CodecRIFUtil.create(CodecRIFUtil.java:88)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.JPEGRIF.create(JPEGRIF.java:43)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.ImageFormatException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 50 more
Exception in thread "main" javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException: All factories fail for the operation "fileload"
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1687)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:819)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:799)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.createNS(JAI.java:1099)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:973)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:1621)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.storeFile(ImageSink.java:37)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.write(ImageSink.java:58)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.write(ImageSink.java:16)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.pipesfilters.Pipe.write(Pipe.java:70)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSource.write(ImageSource.java:77)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSource.run(ImageSource.java:84)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.Program.main(Program.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException: All factories fail for the operation "stream"
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1687)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.FileLoadRIF.create(FileLoadRIF.java:144)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException: All factories fail for the operation "jpeg"
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1687)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.StreamRIF.create(StreamRIF.java:102)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.JPEGImageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(JPEGImageDecoder.java:46)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.CodecRIFUtil.create(CodecRIFUtil.java:88)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.JPEGRIF.create(JPEGRIF.java:43)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.ImageFormatException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 50 more
Caused by:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:819)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createInstance(RenderedOp.java:799)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.createRendering(RenderedOp.java:867)
    at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getRendering(RenderedOp.java:888)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.createNS(JAI.java:1099)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:973)
    at javax.media.jai.JAI.create(JAI.java:1621)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.storeFile(ImageSink.java:37)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.write(ImageSink.java:58)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSink.write(ImageSink.java:16)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.pipesfilters.Pipe.write(Pipe.java:70)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSource.write(ImageSource.java:77)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.ImageSource.run(ImageSource.java:84)
    at at.fhv.students.rotter.systemarchitectures.imageprocessing.Program.main(Program.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException: All factories fail for the operation "stream"
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1687)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.FileLoadRIF.create(FileLoadRIF.java:144)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: javax.media.jai.util.ImagingException: All factories fail for the operation "jpeg"
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1687)
    at javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.invokeFactory(ThreadSafeOperationRegistry.java:473)
    at javax.media.jai.registry.RIFRegistry.create(RIFRegistry.java:332)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.StreamRIF.create(StreamRIF.java:102)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.media.jai.FactoryCache.invoke(FactoryCache.java:122)
    at javax.media.jai.OperationRegistry.invokeFactory(OperationRegistry.java:1674)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/image/codec/jpeg/ImageFormatException
    at com.sun.media.jai.codecimpl.JPEGImageDecoder.decodeAsRenderedImage(JPEGImageDecoder.java:46)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.CodecRIFUtil.create(CodecRIFUtil.java:88)
    at com.sun.media.jai.opimage.JPEGRIF.create(JPEGRIF.java:43)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.ImageFormatException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 50 more
```

Does anybody have an idea?

UPDATE:
I have already tested a bit, and found out that the loading of bmp-Images works sometimes. Then I tried to show the image in a DisplayJAI, instead of writing it into a file. This works for the following bmp-Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDILk.png

But it does not work for the following image (which I converted to a bmp from a jpg with gimp):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQWQa.png

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong?

Comment: Sry, i forgot to answer the answer afterwards - you should be able to look at it now ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution: I also had to add the mlibwrapper.jar-File from the ext-folder to the project...

Comment: TBH I haven't worked with Java for years, and can't tell if I used OpenJDK back then.

Answer (score 3):

I have spent the day searching for answers on this issue. The important thing with JAI is the version of the Java JDK that you use. OpenJDK does not work with it. You need the Oracle Java JDK.

Instructions on getting and installing this are here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre

Or, for those with Ubuntu, here are the quick instrcutions:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

Hope this helps. Maybe this will save you time when you hit this error